# TimeSpan ticks get +1 after save

Tags: c#, dapper

I have an issue with dapper, I don't know how to fix this :

I have a Poco like this :

```
public class Test
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? Time { get; set; }
}
```

The field Time is a MySQL 'TIME'.
If I load a row with Dapper with a Time field with 1000 ticks for example, and I save this Poco without change anything, reload the same row again, Time field is now at 1001 Ticks.

What am I doing wrong ?

**EDIT :**

How I load my row :

```
var testobj = Db.Query<Test>("select * from Test where Id = @id", new {id = Id});
```

How I save it :

```
Db.Execute("replace into Test values (@Id,@Time)", testObj);
```

EDIT 2 :

A timespan object before save :

```
{15:22:24}
    Days: 0
    Hours: 15
    Milliseconds: 0
    Minutes: 22
    Seconds: 24
    Ticks: 553440000000
    TotalDays: 0.64055555555555554
    TotalHours: 15.373333333333333
    TotalMilliseconds: 55344000.0
    TotalMinutes: 922.4
    TotalSeconds: 55344.0
```

and after save :

```
{15:22:25}
    Days: 0
    Hours: 15
    Milliseconds: 0
    Minutes: 22
    Seconds: 25
    Ticks: 553450000000
    TotalDays: 0.64056712962962958
    TotalHours: 15.37361111111111
    TotalMilliseconds: 55345000.0
    TotalMinutes: 922.41666666666674
    TotalSeconds: 55345.0
```

You can see that Ticks 553440000000 and become 553450000000

**EDIT 3 :**

I use Hans tip with my Test class like this :

```
public class Test
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    private TimeSpan? _time;

    public TimeSpan? Time
    {
        get
        {
            if (_time.HasValue)
                return TimeSpan.FromTicks((long)Math.Floor(_time.Value.Ticks / 100000000d) * 100000000);
            return _time;
        }
        set { _time = value; }
    }
}
```

and it works, but it's still odd

Comment: How do you load the time?

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ I updated my question

Comment: sorry I don't understand, the row is loaded with Id = 1 and Time = 1000 ticks, I save this row, reload it, and now Time = 1001 Ticks

Comment: TimeSpan's unit is 100 nanoseconds, dbase engines are not nearly that precise.  MySql only promises 1 microsecond.  You'll get the nearest representable value.

Comment: @HansPassant Is there anything I can do to avoid this issue ?

Comment: Sure, round to microseconds.  Or milliseconds.

Comment: That's a good question. `635864810000000000` _does_ equal `15:23:20` and `635864810010000000` _does_ equal `15:23:21` so it is not a rounding issue on your side. That said, I have no idea what _dapper_ is and what it does behind the scene.

Comment: You can store it as a long or varchar at least for this purpose. I don't know if dapper allows you to define converters from one type to another

Comment: Dapper doesn't do anything here except cast. If you do the exact same thing with raw ADO.NET: do you get the same result?

Comment: @MarcGravell It works with ADO.NET, select the value with reader.GetTimeSpan(), update the row with the same object, and read again, the TimeSpan Ticks are the same

Comment: I'm trying to come up with a working repro, but: the example you give under "A timespan object before save" ... looks like a datetime, not a timespan. Can you clarify?

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes my bad, wrong copy paste, I modify my post. Now I have a problem, if I create a new project with the same Poco, the same connection same dll version etc, I don't have the problem anymore. I don't get it.

Comment: @Baptiste so... something is different between the actual failing and the attempt to repro. I can't see the actual failing code, so it is hard to comment. But there's a very good chance that if you try to isolate the difference between the two, you'll find the actual problem. I can't repro :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much research, there was a mysql plugin developed by my company that doing something special in some cases. Sorry for the loss of time on this issue .

Comment: My favorite type of "bug" - the one where I don't actually need to do anything (except a quick repro attempt), but somehow come out looking useful for taking the time ;p Glad you found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My attempt to repro works fine:

```
[FactMySql]
public void Issue426_SO34439033_DateTimeGainsTicks()
{
    using (var conn = GetMySqlConnection())
    {
        try { conn.Execute("drop table Issue426_Test"); } catch { }
        try { conn.Execute("create table Issue426_Test (Id int not null, Time time not null)"); } catch { }
        const long ticks = 553440000000;
        const int Id = 426;

        var localObj = new Issue426_Test
        {
            Id = Id,
            Time = TimeSpan.FromTicks(ticks) // from code example
        };
        conn.Execute("replace into Issue426_Test values (@Id,@Time)", localObj);

        var dbObj = conn.Query<Issue426_Test>("select * from Issue426_Test where Id = @id", new { id = Id }).Single();
        dbObj.Id.IsEqualTo(Id);
        dbObj.Time.Value.Ticks.IsEqualTo(ticks);

    }
}
```

Whatever the actual problem is: I'm going to need some help to reproduce it. It *seems* to work just fine.

Comment: I have some news, it seems to happen with the customer database I work with, if I create the same table, insert the same line on another schema, it works. I really don't understand.

Comment: @Baptiste and are you 100% sure about the column type in the existing database table?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is, the field `Time` is being modified more than once (overwritten). Maybe by another thread.

To make sure, make the field `readonly` and initialize it once in constructor, and all following attempts to modify the field will be denied by the compiler.

Comment: I don't think so, because after saving the object, the TimeSpan object is still good, but in database I have +1 second.

Comment: You can't set a readonly field, dapper can't set the value when it reads the row and map it to an object

Comment: You should be aware that these encapsulation-related topics can lead to serious errors. You should make your fields readonly and initialize them per object creation (constructor)